# MPU 6050 reading goes erratic when it has small vibrations

Tags: arduino, voltage, transistors, current

**Arduino code below shows how to get the angle values from MPU6050 gyroscope sensor**. This **works extremely well when there is no vibration**. However, if there is vibration coming from dc motors, the values has **erratic fluctuations of +-10 degrees even if the sensor is stationary with small high frequency vibrations coming from DC motors**. May I know if this is solvable which is having **accurate MPU6050 reading when it experience small vibrations of high frequency? How do I adapt it to my code below ?** I will test out your code immediately :)

Thank you for reading and have a nice day :)

```cpp
#include <MPU6050_tockn.h>
#include <Wire.h>

MPU6050 mpu6050(Wire);

long timer = 0;
int counterr = 0;
int y_angle = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Wire.begin();
    mpu6050.begin();
    mpu6050.calcGyroOffsets(true);
}

void loop() {
    delay(5000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000000000000; i++) {
        mpu6050.update();
        if(millis() - timer > 100) {
            y_angle = round(mpu6050.getAngleY());   
            Serial.print("  angleY : ");
            Serial.print(y_angle);
            Serial.println("=======================================================");
            timer = millis();
        }
    }
    delay(1000000);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure mechanical vibrations are the issue, and not other disturbances like electromagnetic interferences?

Comment: @VelVel, I am 100% sure its mechanical because when I dismounted MPU6050, reading becomes stable. When I mount MPU 6050 back to the drone, reading becomes erratic. Do you know how to solve this :) ? Is there arduino code that can solve this issue?

Comment: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/gyro-mechanical-performance.html Get a better gyroscope or at least mount it on a damper. MPU6050 was made for smartphones and remote controls, not mechanical machinery. You say "*erratic fluctuations of +-10 degrees*". Do you mean 10deg or 10deg/s?

Comment: @DKNguyen, yes sir, it fluctuates haha fast

Comment: You can also try to reduce vibration at the source on your drone.

Comment: @DKNguyen, have you used these type MPU 6050 of sensor before? Do you have this problem too?

Comment: No I don't bother using really integrated DSP gyros like the MPU. Most people use them because they are cheap.

Comment: @DKNguyen, what kind of gyro do you use that is not so susceptible to vibration noise ? Can recommend me some?

Comment: I like the CRM series from Silicon Sensing but they cost much more. You should probably try to reduce the vibration in your quadcopter first since the MPU has been used in quadcopters. Like damper mounts for the motors and IMU, balancing props, etc.

Comment: Noise rejection and sensor fusion is an art with these kinds of devices.  It is a matter of pulling a signal out of an enormous amount of noise.  It requires both mechanical and software countermeasures.

Answer (score 2):

The place to start in signal conditioning is always to try to get the cleanest signal practical to work with, and that means mechanical design in this case. Outside of the scope of this answer.

The [MPU6050](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf) has an internal low pass filter (LPF) that can be set as low as 5Hz (up to 256Hz). If you can set it as low as practical for your application and use a data rate that is (say) 10x higher, you may be able to do the rest with a digital filter (but see the first point above).

If the LPF is set too high compared to the data rate, you will not be able to filter out the noise with any digital technique (theoretically the limit is 1:2 but 1:10 is better).

[image]

Comment: Dear sir, can you give the full arduino code that contains the low pass filter ? I do not know how to activate it, and just a few minutes ago, I have tried to reduce vibrations using foam rubber dampers, but still does not work. I believe I have to activate the low pass filter :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that isn't electromatic by placing the gyroscope close to the drone on a fixed surface disconnected from the drone hardware and fly the drone next to it. Another thing you'll probably want to do is run a Kalman filter if your hardware and support it. They estimate the state and can filter somewhat.

But you also need to solve the noise issue and the best way is either going to be use a mechanical separator or EM shielding around the gyroscope. You could also be getting conducted emissions through ground. Another thing is you might be getting RF interference from any radios or other things going on on the drone

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to try to reduce some of the vibration mechanically, but it is possible to try and do it digitally:

I wanna design a first order digital filter with cutoff frequency equal to 1. We start by designing an analog first order low pass filter with cutoff frequency equal to 1 (no need to worry about prewarping):
$$H(s)=\frac{1}{s + 1}$$
Applying the bilinear transform we get:
$$H(z)=\frac{1+z^{-1}}{21-19z^{-1}}$$
applying the inverse z transform we get:
$$y[n] = \frac{x[n] + x[n-1] + 19y[n-1]}{21}$$

Here's a simulation of the system: I added noise to some signal and than applied on it this digital filter, here's the result:
[image]

I applied the filter to your code, here's the modified code:

```
#include <MPU6050_tockn.h>
#include <Wire.h>

MPU6050 mpu6050(Wire);

long timer = 0;
int counterr = 0;
int y_angle = 0;

void setup() {
pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
Wire.begin();
mpu6050.begin();
mpu6050.calcGyroOffsets(true);
}
float last_output = 0; 
float last_input = 0;
void loop() {
delay(5000);
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000000000000; i++) {
    mpu6050.update();
    if(millis() - timer > 100) {
        y_angle = round(mpu6050.getAngleY()); 
        float this_output = (y_angle + last_input + 19*last_output)/21.0;
        last_output = this_output;
        last_input = y_angle;
        Serial.print("  angleY : ");
        Serial.print(y_angle);
        Serial.println("=======================================================");
        timer = millis();
    }
}
delay(1000000);
}
```