# MPU 6050 pull-up resistor

Tags: arduino, voltage, power, current, programming

Referring to [this website](https://electrosome.com/interfacing-mpu-6050-gy-521-arduino-uno/), this is a typical MPU 6050 gyroscope connection and its Arduino code.

After spending some good hours, I believe my problem comes from the hardware because my Arduino code has some delay (400 ms) in the void loop and I believe it does not have any processing issue coming from the code.

Based on my experience, I have used pull-up resistors to solve encoder-step-skipping issues when it undergoes vibration.

How do I attach the pull-up resistors to SCL & SDA pins and the resistors value and do I need to make some changes to my Arduino code below if the pull-up resistor is included? This MPU 6050 (which does not have pull-up resistors) works well when it doesn't experience vibration but angle readings become bad when it has small-vibrations (jittering.) I belive pull-up resistors will help to make this MPU 6050 read accurately when it experiences mini vibrations.

[image]

[image]

```
#include<Wire.h>
 
const int MPU_addr=0x68;
int16_t AcX,AcY,AcZ,Tmp,GyX,GyY,GyZ;
int minVal=265;
int maxVal=402;
double x;
double y;
double z;
void setup(){
Wire.begin();
Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
Wire.write(0x6B);
Wire.write(0);
Wire.endTransmission(true);
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
Wire.write(0x3B);
Wire.endTransmission(false);
Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);
AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
int xAng = map(AcX,minVal,maxVal,-90,90);
int yAng = map(AcY,minVal,maxVal,-90,90);
int zAng = map(AcZ,minVal,maxVal,-90,90);
x= RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-yAng, -zAng)+PI);
y= RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-xAng, -zAng)+PI);
z= RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-yAng, -xAng)+PI);
Serial.print("AngleX= ");
Serial.println(x);
delay(400);
}
```

**MPU 6050 Low Pass filter Activated code** taken from [here](https://how2electronics.com/measure-tilt-angle-mpu6050-arduino/).

Comment: Did you try to set a lower filter bandwith? I think the vibration issues are not related to pull up resistor values. However ist is good practice to add them anyway.

Comment: `This MPU 6050 (which does not have pull-up resistors) ...` are you sure about this? The module shown in your diagram has 2k2 pull-ups already. Assuming you are using the same module, I don't think you need to place any extra pull-up.

Comment: Is the problem really physical vibration?  Does it happen when you wiggle it by hand or does it only happen when the motor is running?

Comment: @JRE, only motor is running. Perhaps, you can try a similar experiment like mine and see how well it goes haha :)

Comment: Not likely.  I don't have an MPU6050 or any use for one.  What I'd do is to solder a 100nF capacitor across the motor power connections, right at the motor.  I'd also connect a 100nF capacitor across the power leads to the MPU6050 module.  I expect you have electrical interference from the motor causing problems.

Comment: @JRE, if you ever use this MPU 6050, can you please share  your MPU 6050 angle readings Arduino code? Maybe it works :)

Comment: @JRE, the motor is powered by external battery. It is not even connected to Arduino

Comment: Right.  It can still cause electrical interference.

Comment: The way the jumper wires with sockets are simply stuck on the pins of the MPU6050 module won't help with vibrations, either.  I'd have soldered all the connections rather than using a breadboard and jumper wires.  I don't trust breadboards at all.

Comment: @JRE, I will try that out and see how well it goes :)

Comment: @JRE, hi, it still doesn't work. Do you think that other pins must be grounded in order to prevent bad readings when vibrating? If someone has this gyroscope, can try to help :)

Comment: Is this the same problem as in your [earlier question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/641775/mpu-6050-reading-goes-erratic-when-it-has-small-vibrations)

Answer (score 2):

It is mandatory to have pull-ups for both lines for I2C.

From wikipedia:

> At the physical layer, both SCL and SDA lines are an open-drain
> (MOSFET) or open-collector (BJT) bus design, thus a pull-up resistor
> is needed for each line.

Usually, 10k pull-ups is sufficient. But I suggest you to check with an oscilloscope for proper edges of signals.

Comment: MPU6050 module in OP's diagram has 2k2 pull-ups.

Comment: @RohatKılıç, I try to seek as many advice as possible :). So, in my updated post, I have my new connections and also Arduino code taken from a website that I mentioned which includes a low-pass filter activated for this MPU 6050.  However, the angle readings are still jumping all over the place when I turn on the mircobrushles motor. Any ideas on how to solve it ? :)

Comment: @RohatKılıç, perhaps, you can try this if you have a microbrushless motor like mine and a MPU 6050 with arduino :).

Comment: I also included 10k pull ups on both signal pins :)